# why can't I use "auto" in codeblocks in linux

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, auto

it's my first time to use `auto` in c++, and I work on linux, but I find it doesn't work at all. I want to know what happened. It's my code:

```
    //<STL container.cpp>
    //date: 2014.3.9 10:45
    #include<iostream>
    //#include<iterator>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        double a= 10.0;
        auto b=a;
        cout<<b;
        //for(auto it = mydata.begin();;it!=mydata.end();it++)
           // cout<<" "<<*it;
        cout<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

and codeblocks told me :

```
error:'b' does not name a type
error:'b' was not declared in this scope
```

I want to know whether codeblocks doesn't refer to `auto` or linux doesn't.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: You must not have C++11 enabled, or the compiler does not support it.

Comment: try `g++ main.cpp -std=c++11`.

Comment: @WiSaGaN I'm using GNU GCC compiler

Comment: Note that CodeBlocks is an IDE, not the actual compiler. You'll have to tell CodeBlocks to run the compiler with the C++11 option. Not sure how to do that off the top of my head.

Comment: @gongzhitaao I have tried this  ,but I find I am not used to g++ in bash ,and it turns out too more mistakes than those in Codeblocks .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refer to this image on how to enable C++11 mode on CodeBlocks.

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend enabling `-Wall` and probably `-Wextra` as well, and fix the warnings it gives you.

Comment: @FredLarson please tell me the details ,ok? Because I have never known about -Wall or -Wextra

Comment: @benjaming: Those options turn on additional compile warnings to let you know about questionable things in your code. Heeding those warnings can go a long way toward solving some baffling problems.

Comment: @FredLarson thanks , I think I'm getting more familiar to codeblocks and c++ with help from you.Thanks a lot.